# Power iteration in R implementation

Tags: r, iteration

I have some trouble with an implementation of a Power iteration in R.
The following is what I got, but it's somehow not working right anymore now, although I just executed it a few minutes ago and it was working fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
A = matrix(c(0,0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.4,0,0,0.6,0,0,0,0,0.8,0,0.2,0,0,0,0,1.0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0,0.7,0),
nrow = 6,
ncol = 6,
byrow = TRUE)
B = matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
nrow = 1,
ncol = 6)
eps = 1
steps = 1

power_test <- function(A,B,eps,stop=100)
{ 
repeat
{
B_new = (B %*% A)
print (steps)
if (norm(abs(B_new) - (B)) <= eps) break
print (B_new)
B = B_new
steps = steps + 1   
if (steps == stop) break
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you want  `if (norm(abs(B_new - B)) <= eps) break
`

Comment: Is there a big difference? I get the same results at least

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow not working right anymore now"? Do you get an error message? Do you get wrong results?